# How to exclude a folder (add a conditional) in windows command line loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am running `Win10`. I have the following in a windows command-line `bat` file and it works great, deleting all `bin` folders (recursively) within a certain folder tree:

```
FOR /d /r . %%d IN (bin) DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"
```

But now there is 1 `bin` folder that needs to be excluded from deletion. Suppose its parent folder is named `XYZ`. How could I run that same loop, but exclude the deletion of `bin` where the parent of the `bin` folder that I want to exclude is named `XYZ`?

Comment: Untested: `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /ad /b /s ^|findstr /ELIC:"\bin" ^|findstr /ELIVC:"\xyz\bin"') DO rd /s /q "%%G"`

Comment: `for /D /R %%d in (bin) do if exist "%%~d" for /D %%p in ("%%~DPd.") do if /I not "%%~NXp"=="xyz" do rd /S /Q "%%~d"`?

Comment: Squashman: yours worked perfectly. THANK YOU. Can you post that as an answer? aschipfl: yours doesn't delete anything.